# Javascript loop through JSON with array

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I need a little help with a loop in JavaScript.
Please see the JSON data below

```
{
    "blogs":{
        "id1":{
            "title":"Title 1",
            "date":"test_date",
            "datestamp":"test_datestamp 1",
            "content":"The content",
            "url":"https:\/\/www.testlink1.com",
            "tags":["move","New"]
        },
        "id2":{
            "title":"Title 2",
            "date":"test_date",
            "datestamp":"test_datestamp 2",
            "content":"The content 2",
            "url":"https:\/\/www.testlink2.com",
            "tags":["Netherlands","Yellow"]
        }
    }
}
```

Next I parse the JSON like below

```
data = JSON.parse(this.response); //This JSON is the result from an AJAX call to a PHP file
```

For using the data I do this

```
for(let id in data.blogs){
    console.log(data.posts[id].date);
    console.log(data.posts[id].title);
    //etc.
}
```

But how can I loop the **tags** array inside this loop?

I tried this but with no result

```
for(let id in data.blogs){
    for(let tag in data.blogs.tags){
    alert(data.blogs[id].tags[tag]);
    }
}
```

Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how can I loop the tags array inside this loop?

You need to identify the blog item currently in the process loop.

Here due example, note the `for-in` as you wrote or the `for-of` loop to cycle the items.

```js
const data = {
  blogs: {
    id1: {
      title: 'Title 1',
      date: 'test_date',
      datestamp: 'test_datestamp 1',
      content: 'The content',
      url: 'https://www.testlink1.com',
      tags: ['move', 'New']
    },
    id2: {
      title: 'Title 2',
      date: 'test_date',
      datestamp: 'test_datestamp 2',
      content: 'The content 2',
      url: 'https://www.testlink2.com',
      tags: ['Netherlands', 'Yellow']
    }
  }
}

for (const blogId in data.blogs) {
  const blogItem = data.blogs[blogId]
  console.log(`looping ${blogItem.title}`)
  for (const tag of blogItem.tags) {
    console.log(tag)
  }
}

for (const blogItem of Object.values(data.blogs)) {
  console.log(`looping ${blogItem.title}`)
  for (const tag of blogItem.tags) {
    console.log(tag)
  }
}
```